# Preserve time stamp when shrinking an image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

My digital camera takes pictures with a very high resolution, and I have a PIL script to shrink them to 800x600 (or 600x800). However, it would be nice for the resultant file to retain the original timestamp. I noticed in the docs that I can use a File object instead of a name in PIL's image save method, but I don't know if that will help or not.

My code is basically
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)

```
# open an image file (.bmp,.jpg,.png,.gif) you have in the working folder
image = Image.open(filename)

width = 800
height = 600

w, h = image.size
if h > w:
    width = 600
    height = 800

name = name + ".jpg"
shunken = image.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
shunken.save(name)
```

Thank you for any help you can give!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`shutil.copystat`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copystat)

It appears that PIL does not save EXIF metadata.
To copy the EXIF data using Python you could use
[pyexiv2](http://tilloy.net/dev/pyexiv2/). This is how [Phatch](http://photobatch.stani.be/), a batch photo resizer program written in Python, deals with EXIF data, for example.

I'm not sure if you're using Ubuntu, but if so, installation is easy since `pyexiv2` is provided by `python-pyexiv2` package.

**Edit:** If you don't mind losing the EXIF metadata, and would simply like to use the EXIF datetime stamp as the resized image's modification date, then you can do it without the `pyexiv2` package, thus saving you an extra dependency. Here's how:

```
import os
import time
import Image
import ExifTags   # This is provided by PIL
img=Image.open(filename,'r')
```

PIL can read EXIF data, but cannot yet write EXIF data. We can access the data using the `_getexif()` method:

```
d = dict((ExifTags.TAGS[k], v) for k, v in img._getexif().items())
print(d['DateTimeOriginal'])
```

Parsing the timestamp may depend on what format the camera uses. This works for my camera; YMMV. The [`dateutils`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) package allows you to parse a wide variety of timestamps without you having to pre-specify the format, but that's another story.

```
timestamp=time.strptime(d['DateTimeOriginal'],"%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Here's an alternative way to swap the width and height:

```
w, h = img.size
width,height = 800,600
if h > w: width,height = height,width
```

Resizing the image, and using `os.utime` to fix the atime and mtime:

```
filename = filename + "-800x600.jpg"
shunken = img.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
shunken.save(filename)
st = os.stat(filename)
os.utime(filename,(st.st_atime,time.mktime(timestamp)))
```

Comment: I ended up using os.utime to change the system's notion of date, but pyexiv2 was very useful it reading the time I really wanted, thank you.

Comment: @Ckhrysze: PIL can read EXIF metadata; it just can't write it. So you could eliminate the dependency on `pyexiv2` if you wish. See my edit for example.

Comment: I had no idea cameras tagged photos with so much information. Once I started playing around with the pyexiv2 library, I actually ended up tagging the new image with a lot of the original data, since I also just learned that lots of programs pick up on them.

On the other hand, being able to do everything with PIL would also be nice, and now I have options. Thanks again!